# Undo functionality in Dojo

Tags: dojo, undo, dojox.grid

I'm using an enhanced grid in Dojo and I would like to implement "Undo" functionality . 
For example after editing a cell, adding/deleting a row the user should be able to revert that action.

Any pointers how to get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well maybe you could get inspiration from this Comand History pattern : https://gist.github.com/c210c0344ca4d4bdfacb

About the actions on DataGrid I assume you know what to do and you were just asking about some "undo mechanism" :)

I hope this will help. I've been using it for a while and it works well

Answer (score 0):

Fetch and save the grid store in some variable before editing . Upon clicking the undo button/link set the grid store with the saved old store.